# Open all links in a new tab in PDF file created with pdfTron

Tags: reactjs, pdftron

I want to open all links from my PDF file generated with `pdfTron` and `react` in a new browser window. If I open the document with a PDF viewer and click on a link, it works fine as the link opens in a new browser tab. But if I initially open the PDF in the browser, when clicking on a link, the new page opens in the same tab and I need it to open on a new tab.
Adding `target="_blank"` on  the `<a>` didn't help although this is working on the HTML template which is generated before the PDF file is created.
Doing it from native JS (using `window.open`) was also impossible.
Is there a way I can add an event listener maybe from pdfTron to tell all the links to open in a new tab? Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't specify this in the PDF itself. You can, however, try modifying your links to point to an intermediate page which opens the link in a new tab. PDFTron has a guide on how to do something like this here:

https://community.pdftron.com/t/how-do-i-open-a-pdf-link-a-url-hypelink-in-a-new-browser-window/172